# xmlhttp.readyState is not changing

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, xmlhttprequest

i was trying to build a application that demonstrate the use of ajax. as i am a newbie in ajax i couldnt able to find the error for my code.  xmlhttp object is creating, rest of the things are not working,
the ready state is not changing to 1 or more than that, i have tried by printing all status values.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Home</title>
<script type="text/JavaScript"> 

 function process()
 {
  var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {

        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.readyState==0)
    {
        food= document.getElementById("username").value;
        xmlhttp.open("GET","food.php?food="+food,true);
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=handleServerResponse();
        xmlhttp.send();     
    }
    else
    {
        setTimeout("process()",1000);
    }
}
```

response function,

```
function handleServerResponse()
{
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {   
                        xmlResponse=xmlhttp.ResponseXML;

                        xmlDocumentElement= xmlResponse.documentElement;

                        message=xmlDocumentElement.firstChild.data;

                        document.getElementById("status").innerHTML="message";

            setTimeout("process()",1000);

        }
}

</script>
</head>

<body >
<form  method="post">
<fieldset><center><h2>Login</h2></center>
    <label>Username</label>
        <input type="text" id="username"  value="" maxlength="20" /> 
    <div id="status" ></div>
        <input type="button" value=" Login " onClick="process()" />
</fieldset>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

php code is below

```
<?php
echo "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes'?>";
echo "<response";
$food=$_GET['food'];
if($food=="ajith")
  echo "Successs";
else
   echo "Invalid";
echo "</response>";   


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

`var` is not optional, use it.

First  `var xmlhttp;` is a local variable, so you would not be able to use it in the other method. Needs to be moved outside of the process function.

Your if check is is impossible

```
xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.readyState==0
```

How can something be 2 values at once?

```
xmlhttp.readyState==4 || xmlhttp.readyState==0
```

---

Next issue is the fact you are not assigning an event handler you are calling it

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=handleServerResponse();
```

needs to be

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=handleServerResponse;
```

---

There is no `ResponseXML`, there is `responseXML`

---

`"message"` is a string, not the variable you defined beforehand.

---

```
var xmlhttp;
function process () {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    if (xmlhttp) {
        var food= document.getElementById("username").value;
        xmlhttp.open("GET","food.php?food="+food,true);
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=handleServerResponse;
        xmlhttp.send();     
    } else {
        //alert("Can not make Ajax request");
    }
}

function handleServerResponse () {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {   
        var xmlResponse=xmlhttp.responseXML;
        var xmlDocumentElement= xmlResponse.documentElement;
        var message=xmlDocumentElement.firstChild.data;
        document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = message;
        window.setTimeout(process,1000);
    }
}
```